# How to set the .Selected property of an item in ASP.NET MVC SelectList using LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to populate a `SelectList` in an action method for a dropdown list in the view. The dropdown gets displayed on the view just fine but the `selected` attribute doesn't show up using the following code:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
    var ctx = new NorthwindEntities();
    var product = ctx.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == ID).SingleOrDefault();
    var selectList = new SelectList(ctx.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
    selectList.Where(s => s.Value == product.CategoryID.ToString()).SingleOrDefault().Selected = true; 
    ViewData["CategoryID"] = selectList;
    return View(product); 
}
```

However, passing the `selectedValue` parameter to `SelectList` constructor does the job:

```
var selectList = new SelectList(ctx.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName", product.CategoryID.ToString());
```

My guess is that Either the `LINQ` expession is the problem or `SelectedItem` can only be specified in the `SelectList` constructor. Any ideas?

Comment: You're right... use your 2nd option.

Comment: Leniel is right. You have a solution that eliminates 1 line of code from your block.

Comment: @David Thanks for the clarification. It implies that SelectList must be instantiated after any calculation/decision-making has been done to pick the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here

[Set selected value in SelectList after instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301854/set-selected-value-in-selectlist-after-instantiation)

If you still think it is wrong then break your linq query up and check to see if you can find an object in the list, and then do an if( obj != null) { selected = true;}

But from what I have read the selected property can only be set in the constructor.

in that link is a wrapper/helper method

```
public static string DropDownListEx(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, SelectList selectList, object selectedValue)
{
    return helper.DropDownList(name, new SelectList(selectList.Items, selectList.DataValueField, selectList.DataTextField, selectedValue));
}
```

That migth help you

Comment: I did try breaking the linq query up and checking for NULL first. But that too didn't do any good. For now, It is clear that which SelectItem to select, should be determined in advance before instantiating the SelectList. Thanks for the helper extension suggestion, should come in handy.