# Create Labels and Values for HTML DropDownList in MVC View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

I have the following, which posts "IT" and "HR" as values in model. I want IT and HR as Label, and 0 and 1 as values to controller.

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", new SelectList(new[] { "IT", "HR" }))
```

And when i get the view, how can i have pre-selected value in the dropdown with the matching value in Department ID in model. So if an item has Id as HR, the dropdown should already have HR as selected, and then a person can change it to IT, and that option can be saved.

Any Help ??
Please note i don't want to change my model.

**ANSWER**
Big Thanks  to  **Terry Nederveld** for giving this answer :

```
 @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", new SelectList(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, int>("IT", 1), new KeyValuePair<string, int>("HR", 2) }, "Value", "Key", (Model.ServiceItem.DepartmentId.Equals(1) ? 1 : 2)))
```

Comment: Create a model Department with variables DepartmentText, DepartmentValue, and fill the data to a list

Comment: I don't want to create a new model here for Department.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Masters approach is the one that I use normally. But since you don't want to change the Model. Here is one approach that will work:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departments", new SelectList(new [] { new KeyValuePair<string, int>( "IT", 0 ), new KeyValuePair<string, int>( "HR", 1 )},"Value", "Key"))
```

Comment: That is one step closer to my goal. I am able to post the correct values, how can i actually set the selected value in this drop down, lets say i have a property in Model with name deptid which will contain either IT or HR, , can i use this property to set the selected value of the above dropdown ?? :) THanks !!

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList( "Departments", new SelectList( new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, int>( "IT", 0 ), new KeyValuePair<string, int>( "HR", 1 ) }, "Value", "Key", Model.deptid ) )` Should do it for you.

Comment: I read it wrong, so you are trying to select the proper item with the key not the value? If the DeptId is an integer of 0/1 then the above will work. Otherwise you will need to change it to us the following `(Model.deptid.Equals("HR") ? 1 : 0)` instead of the Model.deptid directly.

Comment: The above did work, but now i get three values in dropdown, the (HR)selected value, IT and HR !! But there should be only two values, with HR as selected, right ??

Comment: Just checking in, is it working now for you using the (Model.deptid.Equals...)?

Comment: Yeah, i guess you missed my above comment..... It is working, but i get three values in dropdown, HR(Selected Value), IT and HR....

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", new SelectList(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, int>("IT", 1), new KeyValuePair<string, int>("HR", 2) }, "Value", "Key"),Model.ServiceItem.DepartmentId==1?"IT":"HR")  This is what i have :)

Comment: @Nikhil if your Model.ServiceItem.DepartmentId is an integer then all you need that as the SelectedObject argument of the new selectlist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11272/discussion-between-terry-nederveld-and-nikhil)

Comment: Yes, it should, but if i only specify Model.ServiceItem.DepartmentId, i get no selected value... I am testing on an item with value 2, so HR should be selected, but no... if i use ,Model.ServiceItem.DepartmentId==1?"IT":"HR"), i get HR, IT and HR

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using MVC3/4, the easiest way is to add a 'Departments' property to your model. Then you can do this in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department.DepartmentId, Model.Departments)
```

With your model looking like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Departments
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Department Department { get; set; }


    public ViewModel()
    {
        Departments = new List<SelectListItem>();
        //Assume you'll be getting the list from db here?
        Departments .Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "HR", Value = "IdValueHere" });
        Departments .Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "IT", Value = "IdValueHere" });
    }
}
```

This takes care of selecting the correct item.

Comment: For some reasons, I don't want to change model, i want to do it in view only.

Comment: I'd recommend you overcome those reasons, as they appear to be fighting against the framework ;)

Comment: :) Sometimes you have to do it the other way. !!

Comment: Are the reasons that you're using a domain object as the model and you don't want to clutter it with UI specific properties?

Comment: Exactly !! This dropdown box plays a little role in whole thing, i dont want to modify my main object model, because of this.

Comment: This is the point of View Models though. You create a wrapper object for your 'proper' object that contains various properties specifically for UI framework purposes. The main model object is left untouched.

Comment: The above comment was great !! I will follow your advice from now onwards. Buthow i like to know different ways to do the same thing !! :)

Answer (score 0):

See the response from eudaimos (about 50% of way down replies) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301854/set-selected-value-in-selectlist-after-instantiation) for a solution

Comment: apologies - I thought this was how you were supposed to link answers, otherwise how else can the question ever get marked as answered ? I certainly didn't intent to cause an offence - apologies again.

Comment: No offence caused, just my personal opinion; I'd leave links against the questions comments, otherwise your just taking the credit for someone else's answers.