# Set Selected Item in SelectList Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I have a class with the following property. It constructs a `SelectList` object from an existing list, and then sets the selected item.

```
public SelectList ProviderTypeList
{
    get
    {
        SelectList list = new SelectList([...my collection...], "Value", "Key");
        SelectListItem item = list.FirstOrDefault(sli => sli.Text == SelectedProviderType);
        if (item != null)
           item.Selected = true;
       return list;
    }
}
```

However, when this code is finished, `item.Selected` is true. But the corresponding item in the `SelectList` collection is still null.

I can't seem to find a way to update the object in the collection, so that the setting will be used in the resulting HTML.

I'm using `@Html.DropDownListFor` to render the HTML. But I can see that the object within the collection was not modified as soon as this code has executed.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `SelectedValues` property on the list instead of setting `Selected` on the item?

Comment: I just tried to figure that out, but I get the error that `SelectedValues` is read-only and cannot be written to.

Comment: I see. Maybe this answer can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301854/set-selected-value-in-selectlist-after-instantiation

Comment: please add your dropdown creation code

Comment: @DaveA: My question is not about the dropdown creation code. As I stated, I can see in the debugger that it is not set.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an optional additional parameter in `SelectList`

```
SelectList list = new SelectList([...my collection...], "Value", "Key", SelectedID);
```

Check the definition

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, 
object selectedValue);
```

which sets the selected value and is of the same type as the `dataValueField`

Answer (score 1):

I have a list of items called id_waers.

```
var id_waers = db.MONEDAs.Where(m => m.ACTIVO == true).ToList();
```

where the id is "WAERS".

I will create a SelectList with id_waers values, "WAERS" as id and the text to show will be the id too and show the "USD" value as selected

```
ViewBag.MONEDA = new SelectList(id_waers, "WAERS", dataTextField: "WAERS", selectedValue: "USD");
```

[default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hERyQ.png)

[I have another options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGgj5.png)

Comment: Don't just blurt out code. Add some text to explain how it addresses the OP's question. This will improve the long term value of the answer and will prevent it from being deleted by review.

Comment: Thanks! @NightOwl888

Answer (score 0):

Yes this properties are read only, following code should work:

```
        SelectList selectList = new SelectList(Service.All, "Id", "Name");
        foreach (SelectListItem item in selectList.Items)
        {
            if (item.Value == yourValue)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```