# Adding SelectListItem manually to SelectList to use in DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

When I create a SelecList I wish to be able to add SelecListItem's manually and to do this I use this code:

```
List<SelectListItem> Provinces = new List<SelectListItem>();
Provinces.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Northern Cape", Value = "NC" });
Provinces.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Free State", Value = "FS" });
Provinces.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Western Cape", Value = "WC" });

SelectList lstProvinces = new SelectList(Provinces);
```

Instead of this :

```
var lstProvinces = new SelectList(new[] { "Northern Cape", "Free State", "Western Cape" });
```

After I created the SelectList, I pass it to the DropDownListFor via the ViewBag :

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StartPointProvince, (SelectList)ViewBag.Provinces)
```

However when I create the SelectList using the first method, it doesn't work - It adds the 3 values to the dropdown list, but all the values display as:
[image: Code]
*screenshot of output

However when I use the second method, it works fine.
I wish to use the first method because i want to be able to specify the Text AND value of each item.

Comment: Just use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StartPointProvince, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Provinces)` - omit `SelectList lstProvinces = new SelectList(Provinces);`. `DropDownListFor()` accepts `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for the second parameter so its a bit pointless to create a `SelectList` (which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`), and if you did it would need to be `new SelectList(Provinces, "Value", "Text");` but this is just unnecessay overhead

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that [`SelectList(IEnumerable)` constructor doesn't accept `SelectListItem`'s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492864(v=vs.118).aspx) (at least not as `SelectListItem` to add to its `Items` collection). It simply accepts collection of some arbitrary objects that will be used to generate completely unrelated internal `SelectListItem`s collection.

If you want, you can use [`SelectList(IEnumerable, string, string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492864(v=vs.118).aspx) constructor in such way:

```
List<SelectListItem> Provinces = new List<SelectListItem>();
Provinces.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Northern Cape", Value = "NC" });
Provinces.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Free State", Value = "FS" });
Provinces.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Western Cape", Value = "WC" });

this.ViewBag.Provinces = new SelectList(Provinces, "Value", "Text");
```

It will work. But it is **unnecessary**, because you create complex `SelectListItem` items that won't be used by the `SelectList` - it will just treat them as any other data object.

In the same way you can just use some other simpler class in place of `SelectListItem`:

```
public class SelectListModel
{
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}

...
Provinces.Add(new SelectListModel() { Text = "Northern Cape", Value = "NC" });
```

Comment: +1 for for pointing out that SelectListItem is needlessly complex in this scenario. I too was creating List<SelectListItem> because I thought it wasteful to create a custom SelectOption class, but now I see that SelectListItem is a more complex object and that it makes more sense to use simple custom class with no behaviour

Comment: It works perfectly, is there a way how i can set selected value in this ?

Comment: @irshadjm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598512/set-selected-item-in-selectlist-collection

Answer (score 11):

Use DropDownList and name it the same as the model's property name. Mine is "ItemType"

```
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemType, new { @class = "control-label" })
     @Html.DropDownList("ItemType", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ItemTypes, new { @class = "form-control" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemType, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

```
        var types = new List<SelectListItem>();
        types.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Select...", Value = string.Empty });
        types.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "OTC", Value = "0" });
        types.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Generic", Value = "1" });
        types.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Brand", Value = "2" });
        types.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Non-Merchandise", Value = "9" });

        ViewBag.ItemTypes = types;
```

---

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item Type is required")]
    public Int32 ItemType { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 6):

you can change your code from

```
SelectList lstProvinces = new SelectList(Provinces);
```

to

```
SelectList lstProvinces = new SelectList(Provinces, "Value", "Text");
```

and it will display provinces correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need using `SelectList`.
Instead, put `List<SelectListItem>` Provinces into ViewBag and return ViewBag.
Then on the View put:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Dropwonlist", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.YourData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the number of views on this topic, I thought it might help others in giving some further examples of which the option you chose depends on the desired contents of the select list.

I usually prefer to keep the assignment of select dropdown options in a seperate class which is more manageble when creating longer lists, it's also handy to use the same class of optons for more common applications across the app.

C# Class

```
public class CustomFormsSelectDropdownParams
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Example1ItemWidth { get; private set; }
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Example2ItemWidth { get; private set; }
    public static List<SelectListItem> Example3ItemWidth { get; private set; }

    static CustomFormsSelectDropdownParams()
    {
        // ---------
        // Exmaple 1
        // ---------
        // This is OK if you only have a
        // relatively small amount of options to write.
        Example1ItemWidth = new SelectListItem[]
        {
            // First item different to the remaining range.
            new SelectListItem ("100%", "100%"), 
            new SelectListItem ("5em", "5em"),
            new SelectListItem ("6em", "6em"),
            new SelectListItem ("7em", "7em"),
            new SelectListItem ("8em", "8em"),
            new SelectListItem ("9em", "9em"),
            new SelectListItem ("10em", "10em")
        };

        // ---------
        // Exmaple 2
        // ---------
        // This is more practical if you have a large amount of options.
        // NOTE: using this example doesnt allow us to insert any options
        // that are different from the rest, so limited use cases may apply.
        Example2ItemWidth = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ToString() + "em",
            Text = x.ToString() + "em",
        });

        // ---------
        // Exmaple 3
        // ---------
        // This is more practical if you have a large amount of options.
        // This example also allows us to add an option that is a different
        // to the remaining options in the loop.

        // Our first item is bespoke so created seperately.
        var firstDefaultItem = new SelectListItem("100%", "100%");
        // Provides a range between 10 --> 200em
        var remainingItems = Enumerable.Range(10, 191).Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ToString() + "em",
            Text = x.ToString() + "em",
        });

        Example3ItemWidth = new List<SelectListItem>();
        // Add out first bespoke item.
        Example3ItemWidth!.Add(firstDefaultItem);
        // Add the remaining items in a loop.
        foreach (var item in remainingItems)
        {
            Example3ItemWidth.Add(new SelectListItem(item.Text, item.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

Sample HTML Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mb-3 col-3" >
            <label class="form-label">Example 1</label>
            <select class="form-select" asp-items="Classes.CustomForms.CustomFormsSelectDropdownParams.Example1ItemWidth"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mb-3 col-3" >
            <label class="form-label">Example 2</label>
            <select class="form-select" asp-items="Classes.CustomForms.CustomFormsSelectDropdownParams.Example2ItemWidth"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mb-3 col-3" >
            <label class="form-label">Example 3</label>
            <select class="form-select" asp-items="Classes.CustomForms.CustomFormsSelectDropdownParams.Example3ItemWidth"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All three select dropdowns on the page:

[image]

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

Example 3:

[image]

Example 3 was the one that had niggled me for a while, I wasnt sure how to create an select options list as well as adding some other bespoke options at the same time. If i need to to add some more additional besoke options then I would simply add them in what ever order I need, either before the loop, after or in between multiple loops.