# Can not set Selected property of SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selected, selectlistitem

I have a CategoryViewModel as follows:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Products { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedProductIds { get; set; }
}
```

The GET method of CategoryController uses this CategoryViewModel to instantiate an object and adds all Products to this CategoryViewModel object. Then it iterates through all the products and sets the Selected property of products to True which are included in the category object:

```
public ActionResult CategoryController(string categoryId)
{
    CategoryDbContext db = new CategoryDbContext();
    CategoryRepository CategoryRepo = new CategoryRepository(db);
    ProductRepository ProductRepo = new ProductRepository(db);

    Category category = CategoryRepo.GetCategory(categoryId);

    CategoryViewModel categoryView = new CategoryViewModel() 
    {
        Id = category.Id,                   
        Name = category.Name,                             
        Products = from product in ProductRepo.GetAllProducts()
                   select new SelectListItem { Text = product.Name, Value = product.Id, Selected = false}
    };

        foreach (var product in category.Products)
        {
           categoryView.Products.Where(x => x.Value == product.Id).FirstOrDefault().Selected = true;
        }

    return View(categoryView);
}
```

Using the debugger, I observe that foreach executes, but categoryView has all Products with Selected property still set to False.

However, this one works fine:

```
public ActionResult CategoryController(string categoryId)
{
    CategoryDbContext db = new CategoryDbContext();
    CategoryRepository CategoryRepo = new CategoryRepository(db);
    ProductRepository ProductRepo = new ProductRepository(db);

    Category category = CategoryRepo.GetCategory(categoryId);

    CategoryViewModel categoryView = new CategoryViewModel() 
    {
        Id = category.Id,                   
        Name = category.Name,                             
        Products = from product in ProductRepo.GetAllProducts()
                   select new SelectListItem { Text = product.Name, Value = product.Id, Selected = category.Products.Contains(product)}
    };

    return View(categoryView);
}
```

Can someone please explain the difference and why the first one doesn't work?

**EDIT:**
I am using EF 6 and Products and Categories are stored in the database with many-to-many relationship.

Comment: maybe in your foreach loop,that line throws exception.because reference type defaults is null, and null hasn't a Selected property.are u sure it doesn't throw exception?

Comment: @Selman22 Yes, it's in the debug mode and throws error in case of trying to set property of a null reference. But will test again to make sure.

Comment: then my assumption is correct =) check my answer and try again

Comment: @Selman22 Sorry for my vague answer. What I wanted to say was "Yes, it throws exception in case of null reference, but in this case I don,t receive an exception.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by chance while searching for something else: [Set selected value in SelectList after instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301854/set-selected-value-in-selectlist-after-instantiation)

Apparently, the `SelectedValue` property is read-only and can only be overwritten during instantion. When a model is assigned to the view (strongly-typed), the SelectedValue of the SelectListItem is overwritten by its constructor with the value of the object used for page model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, I suspect your foreach loop might throw exception,so you can check whether returning value is null.

```
foreach (var product in category.Products)
{
    var p = categoryView.Products.Where(x => x.Value == product.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    if(p != null) p.Selected = true;
 }
```

Comment: `categoryView.Products` contains all my products which are acquired by   `ProductRepo.GetAllProducts()` and `category.Products` is a subset of these products. So the `Where` statement always returns a non-null object (tested it in debugging). I will test it again and let you know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `foreach()` code block is using `category.Products`. If you use `categoryView.Products`, you should see the change.  You are practically setting Selected of each `category.Products` to true and not use it after.  I hope it is clear to you now.

Comment: Sorry for asking without testing (unfortunately I am away from my PC), but I can't see you point. `foreach()` block iterates through `category.Products` which are products assigned to a specific category. Doing so, I am setting the `Selected` boolean variable of the corresponding `SelectListItem` to true among all products which are viewed.

I can't understand how I can set "Selected" of a product that is assigned to a category. Because the `Product` class does not have such property. Shouldn't the compiler complain then? Please also see my edit to the question. Thanks!

Comment: My worry is that maybe the code `categoryView.Products.Where(x => x.Value == product.Id).FirstOrDefault().Selected = true;` is not returning any `FirstOrDefault()` since maybe the `x.Value` is not equating to `product.Id`.  Sorry if this maybe wrong, I'm just running the code in my brain.  Try this and see if this works `categoryView.Products.Where(x => x == product).FirstOrDefault().Selected = true;`

Comment: Your suggestion is unfortunately not possible to try out since `x` in the lambda function is a `SelectListItem` whereas `product` is an object of `Product` class. Thus, it won't compile. I actually found the reason and sharing it now.